# when conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024) is used no data is received at server side

Tags: android

When i use  **conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)** the program runs and uploads files but the uploaded file is not available (not found) on the uploads folder.

When i remove **setchunk....** line the file uploads successfully and gets saved inside server folder.

---

Main aim of using **conn.setChunkedStreamingMode** was to make my android app upload large file  **greater than 16MB**

Some one please help me with this OUTOFMEMORY error
or 
suggest some other way to upload large files from android app.

```
try {           
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

            //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);


            //conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int)sourceFile.length());
            //conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(maxBufferSize+headerlength);
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding","chunked");

            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");                 


            //conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sourceFile.length());
            //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode((int)sourceFileUri.length() /100);


            //conn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade","HTTP/1.1");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 



            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);                               

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //bufferSize=(int)sourceFile.length();
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) {   

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                dialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();                
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            String a = conn.getContentEncoding();
            String b = conn.getContentType();
            int c = conn.getContentLength();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode +"a="+a+b+c);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.";

                        String sharemsg = "http://my url /files/";

                        String linkmsg = uploadFileName;


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShareActivity.class);

                        i.putExtra("msg", msg);
                        i.putExtra("sharemsg", sharemsg);
                        i.putExtra("linkmsg", linkmsg);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });                
            }    

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Opps! no internet connectivity");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                    + e.getMessage(), e);  
        }
        dialog.dismiss();       
        return serverResponseCode; 

    } // End else block
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your own Server side option like PHP ensure you are have set the right options like max_execution_time and max_upload_size

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_execution_time
```

Comment: i have added 
    **post_max_size=500M**
    **upload_max_filesize=500M**
    **max_execution_time=30**